# JQuery prevent users type numbers and symbols but allow alphabets and spaces

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery function that allows only alphabets and spaces on textbox and prevent users to type numbers and symbols.

My code below is working but the symbols are allowed in textbox.

**HTML**:

```
<input id="inputTextBox" type="text" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inputTextBox").keypress(function(event){
        var inputValue = event.which;
        //if digits or not a space then don't let keypress work.
        if((inputValue > 47 && inputValue < 58) && (inputValue != 32)){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use regex `/[^a-zA-Z\s]/` to match anything, that is not letter or space.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("input change paste", "input", function() {
    var newVal = $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '');
    $(this).val(newVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Letters and spaces only!" />
```

Comment: This fails when I paste ! @ # $ % together, this checks only for first character

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan Add `g` flag to regex

Answer (score 1):

This is code to allow only numeric values, it does't allow characters (alphabetic) and spaces:

```
$('input').keypress(function( e ) {
if((e.which === 32) || (e.which  > 64 && e.which  < 91) || (e.which > 96 && e.which < 123))
    return false;
}); code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the characters you want to allow:

```
$("#inputTextBox").keypress(function(event){
    var inputValue = event.which;
    //if digits or not a space then don't let keypress work.
    if((inputValue > 64 && inputValue < 91) // uppercase
       || (inputValue > 96 && inputValue < 123) // lowercase
       || inputValue == 32) { // space
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jvm4an8b/4/)

Comment: @JairusHolein You were missing the `{` after `$(document).ready(function()`. You didn't load jQuery. And you didn't make the correction from `PreventDefault` to `preventDefault` that Regent commented about. See my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions.
This one only allows spaces and alphabet.

it also displays a span error. you need to make that  with your preferred message. if you uncomment the 7th line.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   $("#inputTextBox").keypress(function(event){
        var isValid = false;
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
        isValid = regex.test($("[id=inputTextBox]").val());
      //  $("#spnError").css("display", !isValid ? "block" : "none");
        return isValid;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should use `$(this).val()` or `this.value`. There's no need to search the DOM when jQuery passes you the element.

Comment: Why do you use `id*=` instead of `id=`. Why don't you use use `$("#inputTextBox").val()`?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake @Barmar,it actually gets all the string that have theis substring, so just use: [name="value"]  , answer edited.
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Why do you prefer `[id=XXX]` instead of `#XXX`? That's the standard way to refer to an ID in a selector.

Comment: Line `var isValid = false;` is pretty useless. Just remove it and change to `var isValid = regex.test($("[id=inputTextBox]").val());`

Comment: Well, actually the whole logic is incorrect: your code will allow first incorrect symbol and then will not allow any characters. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx8n2og4/). Please test your code before posting to avoid situations when your code doesn't do what is required.